# Is it possible to measure the page swapping time in a c++ code?

Tags: c++, networking, memory, cpu, latency

Does anyone know about how to measure the data caching and/or the page swapping time in a program?

I am running a large finite element analysis on a high performance cluster (linux 64bits), the program is slow at the beginning and the time it takes seems to be quite random. I guess it has something to do with the data caching and page swapping.

Any idea how to measure it? And how to measure it in parallel?

Comment: Or possibly data caching.  Maybe a tool like [perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Counting_with_perf_stat)?

Comment: You ask a question like that and don't specify your OS?

Comment: I'm using a high performance cluster that has linux 64 bits installed.

Comment: I suggest using `taskstats`' `swapin_delay_total` field.  It's easier to get major page fault counts, that doesn't translate so directly to delay but may be adequate to diagnose the performance issues.  "And how to measure it in parallel?" - in parallel with what?